# Jmeter Https recording using Iphone

Tags: iphone, proxy, jmeter

I am having trouble recording my https traffic in jmeter and always get this error message. I havent had any trouble recording the regular traffic though.

Response code: Non HTTP response code: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException
Response message: Non HTTP response message: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No X509TrustManager implementation available

what I have tried so far to overcome this problem

1) Installed Jmeter temp certificate in my device

2) Added HTTP(s) domain in the recording controller

3) Using Http client 4  in http sampler setting

4) Cleared the history in iphone
5) tried using http request defaults

I have Iphone6 ,its MAC OSX yosemite. Jmeter version 2.13

Comment: What version of jMeter?  What version iOS and iPhone?   I ran through your case recording https traffic from FlipBoard and had no issues recording or playing back.   I ran the test locally and then ran it remotely from multiple locations 20 threads with loop 10 distributed running on 3 agents [Record from iPhone Test Case](https://www.redline13.com/share/testplan/15191)  The JMX file is available as well.  Would be interested to know if you can run that JMX locally as well?

Comment: edited my question with additonal details. I know I am doing a very silly thing and just need a pointer in the right direction

Comment: check this once - http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-record-ios-application-http-requests/

Comment: Can you create this issue with hitting any https endpoint?  or is it specific to your domain?    Do you know the endpoint?  What happens when you open that endpoint in a browser?

Comment: I have already follow whats there in the link.. this is the endpoint I am hitting is   [link] https://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?[link] its the google public ad link Url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to import `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` (it's being generated in /bin folder of your JMeter installation when you start [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder).

- Locate the file
- Send yourself an email message with the file enclosed
- Open the email on the mobile device
- Install the certificate

It should be enough to resolve your problem.

The easier way is to use [Mobile Recorder](https://docs.blazemeter.com/customer/portal/articles/1946705-mobile-recorder) service instead.